# bash for loop with grave command

Tags: bash, shell, curl, for-loop, awk

A web server contains a couple of log files and I try to write some shell script using curl and awk to find the files based on some pattern and then download. 
Probably there are smarter ways to do all that stuff (also the awk part - I am a beginner) but I kind of decided to do the downloading part in a for loop and when I run it directly in the shell it did download the files.

```
# for line in `curl -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $link 2>/dev/null | awk -v pat="$pat2" '$0~ "/"pat".log"'| awk -v val=$host1 -F '"' '{print val $2}'`; 
do 
echo "Downloading $line"; 
curl -O -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $line 2> /dev/null; 
done
```

Now I am struggling to get that for loop integrated in the script. This is my current attempt but it somehow does not execute the command I graved and put to the list var. So any advise on how to accomplish that part or showing a cleaner approach would be highly appreciated.

```
test_pass=`curl -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $link 2>/dev/null | grep '401 - Authorization Required' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1 -`
failed="401"
list=$(curl -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $link 2>/dev/null | awk -v pat="$pat2" '$0~ "/"pat".log"'| awk -v val=$host1 -F '"' '{print val $2}')

if  [[ "$test_pass" = "$failed" ]]; then
 echo "Wrong Password."
 exit 1
else
 echo "Starting Download"
for line in $list; do
 echo "Downloading $line"
 curl -O -X GET -k --user $user:$pass $line 2> /dev/null
done
fi
```

Comment: Just try the `list=$(curl...)` line on its own at a shell prompt, then check the value of `list` with `echo "$list"`. Once you check that is working you can try to put into something more complicated. Even take your first script and extend it by one line. Add one thing at a time and check it works after each step.

Comment: You can also write `set -x` somewhere in your script to enable debugging from there onward.

Comment: what is the output of " echo "Downloading $line" ?

Comment: `echo $list` returns some files but all in one line whereas when I run the curl command in the shell it returns the list of files and each file in a new line.

Comment: `echo "Downloading $line` does not return anything I only get the "Startting Download" line. that is it.

Comment: so I have the feeling I cannot use awk the way I wanted. If I use grep and sed instead it does work: list=`curl -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $link 2>/dev/null | grep -oE 'href=".*/'${pat}'.*"' | sed -e 's/href="/https:\/\/'${host}'/g;s/"//g'`
thanks also for the `set -x`

Comment: The reason `echo $list` displays a single line is that it is an error to not quote your strings. You should find that `echo "$list"` displays what you expect.

Comment: The first line in your code above starts with '#': `# for line in ...`.  This makes it a comment, and will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using [bash arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

an assignment of the form `var=($(cmd))` sets `$var` to an array containing one entry for each result returned by `cmd`

`${var[@]}` will then expand to all entries in the array, separated by whitespace

note that if there are spaces (or anything worse, e.g. newlines) in the filenames you're trying to get, this will need much more work

here's your code, slightly modified to make `$list` an array:

```
test_pass=`curl -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $link 2>/dev/null | grep '401 - Authorization Required' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1 -`
failed="401"
list=($(curl -X GET -k  --user $user:$pass $link 2>/dev/null | awk -v pat="$pat2" '$0~ "/"pat".log"'| awk -v val=$host1 -F '"' '{print val $2}'))

if  [[ "$test_pass" = "$failed" ]]; then
 echo "Wrong Password."
 exit 1
else
 echo "Starting Download"
for line in "${list[@]}"; do
 echo "Downloading $line"
 curl -O -X GET -k --user $user:$pass "$line" 2> /dev/null
done
fi
```